# Spreadsheet gear cell with list validation selection changed event?

Tags: spreadsheetgear

I have list validation on a few cells and would like to shade the cell if a value is selected/changed from dropdown(filter list). For regular cells, I use EndEdit event which apparently doesn't fire in this case.

Could anyone please point me to right event to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There is no specific event that fires for a cell validation dropdown selection action.  The WorkbookView.[CellEndEdit](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.7.0/#SpreadsheetGear2012.Windows.Forms~SpreadsheetGear.Windows.Forms.WorkbookView~CellEndEdit_EV.html) event is solely used for "edit mode"--when a user manually types some value into a cell--and there is nothing in SpreadsheetGear API to expand edit mode to include other forms of input.

The WorkbookView.[RangeChanged](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.7.0/#SpreadsheetGear2012.Windows.Forms~SpreadsheetGear.Windows.Forms.WorkbookView~RangeChanged_EV.html) event *will* fire whenever a change is made to a cell, including via a cell validation listbox; however, many other actions trigger this event as well, such as changing a cell's NumberFormat, font formats, etc; or inputting a cell value in some other way such as pasting a value, FillDown, Clear, etc.   Still, you may be able to use this event to, within some reasonable assurance, get the information you need.

Below is some sample code that demonstrates how you could detect whether [RangeChanged](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.7.0/#SpreadsheetGear2012.Windows.Forms~SpreadsheetGear.Windows.Forms.WorkbookView~RangeChanged_EV.html) was called from a single cell containing cell validation.  Additional conditions are used to ensure to the best of our ability that the event was triggered by the user changing a value via the validation dropdown list.  Again, this still isn't 100% foolproof for the reasons listed above.

```
private void workbookView_RangeChanged(object sender, SpreadsheetGear.Windows.Controls.RangeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // Did this RangeChanged action affect only a single cell?
    if(e.Range.CellCount == 1)
    {
        IRange cell = e.Range;
        // Does the cell even have cell validation?
        if(cell.HasValidation)
        {
            IValidation validation = e.Range.Validation;
            // Is the validation applied to this cell of the "List" type and 
            // does the inputted value pass validation checks?
            if(validation.Type == ValidationType.List && validation.Value)
            {
                // Do something here, such as shade the cell...
                cell.Interior.Color = SpreadsheetGear.Colors.LightGray;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please see the documentation for the [IValidation](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.7.0/#SpreadsheetGear2012.Core~SpreadsheetGear.IValidation_members.html) interface members for more information on each of the properties used above.

Comment: I was able to use this to get the desired result but as you warned it fires a lot of other events and I had to do a bit of dirty stuff around it. I don't believe this is an answer someone looking in the future should consider, so, I am not marking this as the correct answer. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: I understand.  It's not ideal by any means, but that's about the best that can be done (at least that I can think of) with the API's current offerings.  I work for SpreadsheetGear and we do keep track of requests for features like "Validation List Value Changed Event."  Feel free to send us a message at support@spreadsheetgear.com with your name and email address and I'll add you to this feature request so we can contact you if/when this does become available, though I cannot say when that might occur.